# Updating HTML/CSS so that content displays to the right instead of below

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have tried to simplify my problem into the below snippet - my real project is using React but this should demonstrate the issue:

```css
.page-container {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

.heading-tab {
  height: 72px;
  width: 294px;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.heading-text {
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row-group {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 0.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.row-content {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  padding-right: 24px;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="heading-tab">
    <p class="heading-text">
      Heading 1
    </p>
  <div>

  <div class="row-group">
     <div class="row-content">My name is CTS and my alignment is all wrong!</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

What I want to do is display my `row-group` (and it's contents) horizontally level with the `heading-tab` - as you can see it currently sits below but I need it to set just at the end of my `heading-tab` div?

Comment: You have set a fixed width on your heading-tab which the other elements are inside.

Comment: Yes - but heading tab doesn't wrap the `row-group` - the element that I'm trying to impact - `heading-tab` and `row-group` are on the same level.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you wanted the row-group to be alongside the headings.

Comment: How we can put `row-group` to the same level as `heading-tab` if here two such levels?

Comment: Updated my code snippet to make it easier to understand - hope this is clearer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flexbox on the heading tab should work.

```css
.page-container {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

.heading-tab {
  height: 72px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items:flex-start;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
}

.heading-text {
  padding-top: 22px;
  padding-bottom: 22px;
  padding-left: 32px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.row-group {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 0.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.4rem;
}

.row-content {
  padding: 0.25rem;
  padding-right: 24px;
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="page-container">
  <div class="heading-tab">
    <p class="heading-text">
      Heading 1
    </p>
  <div>

  <div class="row-group">
     <div class="row-content">My name is CTS and my alignment is all wrong!</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```